# SIte generated ip seconds php

Tags: php

[image]
I was wondering what this web developer did to make it so it generates user IP and displays the amoutn of seconds it took to load the site. I believe it was made of PHP but i'm not sure.

Comment: To get the ip address: look up https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server and 'REMOTE_ADDR'. for the timing look up: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php and store the start time in a variable before the script starts and another variable for when to script ends - subtract end time from start time.

Answer (score 1):

Adding as an answer to what mentioned in the comment by @jeff. You can get the ip address by PHP's [$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server) array. It contains a `REMOTE_ADDR` index which gives the IP address from which the user is viewing the current page.

For calculating script execution time, you can use [microtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime). Have a look at the example:

```
$start = microtime(true); // Put this at beginning of your script

//your actual script here

$time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start; // Put this at the end of your script
// $time_elapsed_secs will give you time taken by script to execute in seconds
```

Comment: I'm confused. So how would I end up echoing this statement so that it shows once the user inspects elements?

Comment: Just echo `$time_elapsed_secs`. Ex:- `echo $time_elapsed_secs`

Comment: Alright so I have this at the moment after reading the microtime.

<?php
$start = microtime(true);
?>
then this
<?php
echo 'Generation took: ' . (microtime(true) - $start) . ' seconds';
?> and i'm getting this weird E at the end.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do but the above piece of code is tested by me and it works fine. If you can show me your full script then may be I can help you out.